# python joblib Parallel on Windows not working even "if __name__ == '__main__':" is added

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, parallel-processing, syntax-error

I'm running parallel processing in Python on Windows. Here's my code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def f(x): 
    return sqrt(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10))
```

Here's the error message:

```
Process PoolWorker-2:  
Process PoolWorker-1:  
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "C:\Users\yoyo__000.BIGBLACK\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()   
File "C:\Users\yoyo__000.BIGBLACK\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   
File "C:\Users\yoyo__000.BIGBLACK\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
task = get()   
File "C:\Users\yoyo__000.BIGBLACK\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py", line 363, in get
return recv()  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Comment: You probably want to add a return statement `def f(x): return sqrt(x)`.

Comment: no it's the same. also i read somewhere that canopy handles things differently so i try to add `sys.stdout.flush` after `sqrt(x)`, which doesn't work either

Comment: No, it's not. The return value is `None`, if you don't specify `return`.

Comment: okay i have added `return` but it still gives me the same error message

Comment: The given code works for me. Did you try to execute it from the Python CLI? How do you execute the code?

Comment: @YKosinska There seems to be error in delay function call. Just have a look at the parameters that you are sending. analysed from the traces. just no need to do anything with the `return` statement.

Comment: nah if i change `f` to `sqrt` then it's fine. so it's a problem in defining the function. the __name__ == '__main__' doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 15):

According to [this site](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/174) the problem is Windows specific:

> Yes: under linux we are forking, thus their is no need to pickle the
>   function, and it works fine. Under windows, the function needs to be
>   pickleable, ie it needs to be imported from another file. This is
>   actually good practice: making modules pushes for reuse.

I've tried your code and it works flawlessly under Linux.
Under Windows it runs OK if it is run from a script, like `python script_with_your_code.py`. But it fails when ran in an interactive python session. It worked for me when I saved the `f` function in separate module and imported it into my interactive session.

**NOT WORKING:**
Interactive session:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> from joblib import Parallel, delayed

>>> def f(x):
...     return sqrt(x)

>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     a = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10))
...
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py", line 359, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

**WORKING:**
fun.py

```
from math import sqrt

def f(x):
    return sqrt(x)
```

Interactive session:

```
>>> from joblib import Parallel, delayed
>>> from fun import f

>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     a = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10))
...
>>> a
[0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 2.8284271247461903, 3.0]
```

Comment: @kchomski nice post. do you know why we need to use if __name__ == '__main__'  in an interactive session? is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Joblib is working on my Windows 10 when I am using the version `1.19.5 of numpy`. I upgraded all outdated package; to do that you can run the following command:

```
pip list --outdated
pip install --upgrade
```

or you use `pip_upgrade_outdated` which upgrades all outdated packages by doing `pip install pip-upgrade-outdated` and `pip-upgrade-outdated` according this [this site](https://pypi.org/project/pip-upgrade-outdated/#description)