# LDA model and joblib parallel computing error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, joblib

I have some code that does an LDA model on a bunch of CSV lines.

```
lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(
    n_components=20,           # Number of topics
    max_iter=10,               # Max learning iterations
    learning_method='online',   
    random_state=100,          # Random state
    batch_size=128,            # n docs in each learning iter
    evaluate_every = -1,       # compute perplexity every n iters, default: Don't
    n_jobs = -1,               # Use all available CPUs
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lda_output = lda_model.fit_transform(data_vectorized)
    print(lda_model)
```

I ran it the first time without the `if_name_ line` and had no issues.  The second time I ran it, I had the error

```
ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without
protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To
use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop
using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation
on Parallel for more information.
```

So I tried to add the `if_name_` code to get it to work.  I'm still having issues.  I've tried inserting that in various spots of my code (I'm on Windows) and not getting anything to work.  Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Are you using IPython (e.g. Jupyter)? There is a known issue when using `joblib` on windows with interactive python.

Comment: I'm using the Spyder environment which I believe uses the IPython console.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll see if I can work around that.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452694/python-joblib-parallel-on-windows-not-working-even-if-name-main) for a possible solution.